# writing a procedure with named stack parameters

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

what does it mean to create a procedure in assembly with named stack parameters ? 
Is it like `proc_name proc uses eax ebx` ? Is that a procedure with named stack parameters ?
I have to use the procedure like `ìnvoke printArray, ADDR theArray, num_rows, num_cols`
So it looks that this offset of the array will go somewhere along with the values of other 
two variables. But I not sure how to write it and how to access this parameters being passed

I have written a code here using named parameters but it throws errors : 
like `undefined symbol : sum2`

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
number1 dword 1
number2 dword 2
.code


main proc
mov eax, number1
push eax
mov eax, number2
push eax
invoke sum2, number1, number2
main endp


sum2 proc, number11:dword, number12:dword

ret
sum2 endp

end main
```

Comment: It has no meaning in assembly generally, only in MASM's `proc` stuff that lets you give names to your stack args for use within the procedure definition (not when calling it).  `uses` will make it save/restore registers for you, that's a separate thing.

Comment: I don't think there should be any comma after `PROC`.

Comment: Also, since you put the `invoke` before the definition of the procedure, you may have to specify the procedure prototype first. I.e. put something like `sum2 PROTO :DWORD, :DWORD` before `main`.

Comment: If you don't insist on MASM, you can find an inspiration how to create an invokable  **Procedure** with named stack parameters (and local stack variables) withou having to specify any prototypes: https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/stdcal32.htm#pcStdCall32

Comment: @Michael putting the sum2 function before the main worked!! Thanks a lot

Comment: I am little bit surprised even nowdays languages require you to define functions in order. Like Java doesn't but assembly, C, C++ and probably some more have this restriction. C++ being a modern language should have removed this limitation by now

Comment: Most assembly languages don't have any such requirement; you can `call` or `jmp` to any symbol, whether it's defined before or after the current line.  Even for assemble-time `foo equ 123` constants.  If you don't like MASM's style, don't use it.  As for C++, it evolved out of C, which as designed to be able to be compiled on machines with tiny RAM, not parsing the whole compilation unit before starting to emit machine code.